# MVC razor foreach throwing compilation error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to loop through some code from my model in razor.

TagGroups is a list of TagGroups(easy) and Tags apart of that tag group. Then I have a respondent who has selected a tag out of this tag groups and his selection is stored inside of his respondent data.

```
                @foreach (var tagGroup in @Model.TagGroups)
                { 
                    <optgroup label="@tagGroup.Name">
                        @foreach (var tag in tagGroup.Tags)
                        {
                            var selectedTag = @Model.Respondent.Tags.Where(r => r.Id == (int)tag.Id);

                            if (selectedTag != null)
                            { 
                                <option selected="selected">@tag.Name</option>
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                <option>@tag.Name</option>
                            }
                        }
                    </optgroup>
                }
```

Problem is that this throws a compilation error? I have even tried to add "@" before the if selectedTag which then says the @ is not necessary inside a block of code.

I want the output to look like so:

```
<optgroup label="NFC NORTH">
                        <option selected="selected">Chicago Bears</option>
                        <option>Detroit Lions</option>
                        <option>Green Bay Packers</option>
                        <option>Minnesota Vikings</option>
                    </optgroup>
```

Comment: If you have a compilation error, you should post the error message

Comment: Side note: `Enumerable.Where` never returns null...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to add a @ inside of C# code part:

```
@foreach (var tagGroup in @Model.TagGroups)
```

should be

```
@foreach (var tagGroup in Model.TagGroups)
```

And

```
var selectedTag = @Model.Respondent.Tags.Where(r => r.Id == (int)tag.Id);
```

should be

```
var selectedTag = Model.Respondent.Tags.Where(r => r.Id == (int)tag.Id);
```